# Bold section table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, bold

I define new command with \tenbai with the level of section. How to get just \tenbai bold and others sections not bold in the table of content? Thank you

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\newcounter{sobai}
\newcommand{\tenbai}[1]{%
    \par
    \stepcounter{sobai}%
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
        \hline \hline
        \hfill\bfseries\huge\strut \S\thesobai. #1\hfill\mbox{} \\
        \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\S\thesobai. #1}%
    \par\nobreak
}
\begin{document}
\tenbai{Số phức}
\section{Khái niệm số phức - Hai số phức bằng nhau}
\section{Phép cộng, trừ và nhân hai số phức}
\section{Số phức liên hợp - Môđun của số phức}
\section{Phép chia cho số phức khác 0}
\end{document}
```

I would like to make the $\S 1$ Số phức bold but not others sections such as \section{Khái niệm số phức - Hai số phức bằng nhau}...

Answer (score 2):

As an easy option, you can use the `sectsty` package to redefine section font. Other options exit like `titlesec` package or even redefining the `section` macro in the `article` class.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\normalfont}

\newcounter{sobai}
\newcommand{\tenbai}[1]{%
    \par
    \stepcounter{sobai}%
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
        \hline \hline
        \hfill\bfseries\huge\strut \S\thesobai. #1\hfill\mbox{} \\
        \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\S\thesobai. #1}%
    \par\nobreak
}
\begin{document}
\tenbai{Số phức}
\section{Khái niệm số phức - Hai số phức bằng nhau}
\section{Phép cộng, trừ và nhân hai số phức}
\section{Số phức liên hợp - Môđun của số phức}
\section{Phép chia cho số phức khác 0}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: My intention is just get the \tenbai be bold in just table of content and others sections are not, not in the content of article.